# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in 

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

```
$results = mysql_query("select * from classpics");

foreach($results as $uno) {
    echo '<td valign="middle" align="center"><a class="neutral" href="../images.php?id=' . $uno['id'] . '"><img src="'. $uno['thumbs'].'" border="0" /></a>';
}
```

Comment: 2.5hr before year 2011, yet I still seeing people using mysql_query, am I back to the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mysql_query` returns a **[resource id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php)**, you should fetch an **array**:

```
$results = mysql_query("select * from classpics");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
  echo '<td valign="middle" align="center"><a class="neutral" href="../images.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '"><img src="'. $row['thumbs'].'" border="0" /></a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should fetch data from result

```
while($data=mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
echo '<td valign="middle" align="center"><a class="neutral" href="../images.php?id=' . $uno['id'] . '"><img src="'. $uno['thumbs'].'" border="0" /></a>';
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query` returns [resource](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php), not an array or any other container. Use [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) to fetch the next result.

```
while ($uno = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<td valign="middle" align="center"><a class="neutral" href="../images.php?id=' . $uno['id'] . '"><img src="'. $uno['thumbs'].'" border="0" /></a>';
}
```